# Oracle WebCenter Sites Configuration fails

Tags: oracle, webcenter

I have the following stack:

RH6/Oracle12c using PLGORCL pluggable database as SID/WebLogic12c/WebCenter Sites 12c

I am following the guide Installing and Configuring Oracle WebCenter Sites. 
I have run rcu and config and I have started Node Manager, WebLogic and the WebCenter1 Server.
I am using http://192.168.106.144:7006/sites/sitesconfig to configure the domain.
The configuration fails with the error "Error!There was a problem with the configuration and it could not be completed."
The first error in the stack displayed is:

[2017-03-29T21:44:56.188+00:00] [wcsites_server1] [ERROR] [] [oracle.wcsites.security.context] [tid: 119] [userId: ] [ecid: 374d734d-e63e-4c60-85c1-5e75f64a511e-0000002c,0] [APP: ROOT] [partition-name: DOMAIN] [tenant-name: GLOBAL] Unexpected exception: com.fatwire.security.common.CredentialStoreException: JPS-01033: Cannot set credential. Reason oracle.security.jps.service.policystore.PolicyObjectAlreadyExistsException: java.sql.SQLIntegrityConstraintViolationException: ORA-00001: unique constraint (DEV_OPSS.IDX_JPS_RDN_PDN) violated[[

I have reinstalled the webcenter sites product, including dropping the schema using rcu and uninstalling using ../oui/bin/deinstall.sh
The installation fails again. Anyone knows what I am missing?

Answer (score 0):

I have reinstalled the schema with a new prefix, reinstalled the webcenter as well as infrastructure components and installed into a new ORACLE_HOME. The product is now up and running on Linux Centos 6, Oracle 12c pluggable database. This issue is resolved. I think the issue was related to me not removing the ORACLE_HOME contents entirely. Up and running now.